# Java Mailgun API Call getting Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, mailgun

I am using the code below to send an HTML message.  When I make the call, I am getting 400 Bad Request Error.  All my parameters look correct.  Can anyone see what could be wrong?

```
public ClientResponse SendHTMLEMailMessage( MailingList aMailingList, String subject, String messageToSend, String pathToFileAttachments ) 
{
    ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
    cc.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
    client = Client.create(cc);
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter( "api", Config.instance().getApiKey() ) );

    WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.lmsnet.com/messages");
    FormDataMultiPart formData = new FormDataMultiPart();
    formData.field( "from", Config.instance().getLmsEblastFromEmailAddress() );
    formData.field( "bcc", aMailingList.getAddress() );
    formData.field( "subject", "A Message From Lieberman Management Services" );
    formData.field("text", messageToSend );

    return webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need at least a `To` address. The mailgun documentation is not very clear about the exact required fields. You should try that. You could just use the same sender address or an invalid destination address in the same domain like `no-reply@domain.com`.

Comment: Thank you so much sargue!  OMG I can't believe it was that simple.  UGH!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the mailgun docs are a bit disapointing regarding these basic facts.